# RESTful Laravel controller not picking up Destroy() method

Tags: php, laravel, destroy

```
Structure: views/agents/alert/index.blade.php
```

Form to delete 'notification':

```
{{ Form::open(
    array('url'=>'agents/alert/delete/'. $alerts->id, 'role'=>'form')) }}
{{ Form::hidden('_method', 'DELETE') }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" id="archive">Archive</button>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

AgentsController:

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $alert = Alert::find($id);
        $alert->delete();

        return Redirect::to('/agents/')
        ->with('message-success', 'Your alert was successfully archived.');
    }
```

Routes.php:
/* Agent's Route */

```
Route::get('agents/alert/{id}', 'AgentsController@Show');
Route::get('agents/alert/delete/{id}', 'AgentsController@Destroy');
Route::controller('agents', 'AgentsController');
```

I am correctly referencing the URL called when the user presses delete, however, the error presented is 'Controller Method Not Found'.

Any help I'd be thankful of.

Comment: Try `AgentsController@destroy` (hint: case-sensitive). Also, as a note, I would avoid using a `GET` request without any authentication to delete an object. I could easily write a program to delete all of your alerts :)

Comment: Hi Sam, it still returns the same error. The route above for @show, works with and without capitals. Ha, you read my mind, I intend to do that also, just not sure how!

Comment: Hmm, try removing the `Route::controller()` line.  If you are defining all of your routes manually, you shouldn't need to use Laravel's RESTful controller method (this will automatically route requests like `GET agents/test` to `AgentsController@GetTest`).

Comment: To take care of your other problem: try making the form POST and then make sure the `_method:DELETE` parameter is sent.  This will be a good initial layer of protection.

Comment: Hi Sam, if I remove the `Route::controller()` line, I'm unable to access my /agents/ `getIndex()`, view.

Comment: Does it fix your initial problem of `Controller Method Not Found`?  If so, you have two options.  Either define another route for the index `Route::get('agents', 'AgentsController@GetIndex`);` or make your other two URLs more "RESTful" (`DELETE agents/alert` routes to `deleteAlert()` and `GET agents/alert` routes to `getAlert()`).

Comment: Hi Sam, understood. Deleting the `Route::controller()` doesn't resolve the delete issue. It's interesting though, if I set the `destroy()` route to the `show` route, upon viewing an alert, it successfully deletes. By adding the /delete/ into the equation seems to mess things up.

Comment: Why don't just use one `RESTful` controller without mixing them ?

Comment: Are you able to go to `/agents` without any problems?  Perhaps the problem is stemming from: `return Redirect::to('/agents/')`?

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha, the index where the `destroy` method needs to be called from is inside a subdirectory. I'm unsure if this makes a difference? @Sam, if I keep the `Route::controller()` in, I can access it no problem.

Comment: This is the rendered HTML - `<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8888/agents/alert/delete/21" accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="TG4zmbMr4ZutTfQ2PsU20uDllSvnOoJyx67dJTbE">       <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" id="archive">Archive</button></form>`

Comment: If I delete the `@destroy` route, and change the form URL to just /agents/21 <- Example ID to be deleted, the `Error, Controller not found` still appears!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should perform a DELETE on a resource.

If you have an alert with a unique URL `agents/alert/{id}` you should do a DELETE method on the same URL.

```
Route::delete('agents/alert/{id}', 'AgentsController@Destroy');
```

Create a form that can be submitted to delete the resource:

```
{{ Form::open(array('method' => 'DELETE', 'action' => array('AgentsController@Destroy', $alert->id))) }}
```

More information on RESTful controllers [here](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers).

Also try to use [`named routes`](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#named-routes) instead of `action`.